# R neuralnet does not converge within stepmax for time series

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, convergence

I'm writing a neural network for prediction of elements in a time series `x + sin(x^2)` in R, using the `neuralnet` package. This is how training data is being generated, assuming a window of 4 elements, and that the last one is the one that has to be predicted:

```
nntr0 <- ((1:25) + sin((1:25)^2))
nntr1 <- ((2:26) + sin((2:26)^2))
nntr2 <- ((3:27) + sin((3:27)^2))
nntr3 <- ((4:28) + sin((4:28)^2))
nntr4 <- ((5:29) + sin((5:29)^2))
```

Then, I turn these into a data.frame:

```
nntr <- data.frame(nntr0, nntr1, nntr2, nntr3, nntr4)
```

Then, I proceed to train the NN:

```
net.sinp <- neuralnet(nntr4 ~ nntr0 + nntr1 + nntr2 + nntr3, data=nntr, hidden=10, threshold=0.04, act.fct="tanh", linear.output=TRUE, stepmax=100000)
```

Which, after a while, gives me the message

```
Warning message:
algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax 
Call: neuralnet(formula = nntr4 ~ nntr0 + nntr1 + nntr2 + nntr3, data = nntr,     hidden = 10, threshold = 0.04, stepmax = 100000, act.fct = "tanh", linear.output = TRUE)
```

Can anyone help me figure out why it is not converging? Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

`Warning message:`
`algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax`means your algorithm reached the limited steps before it is converged. If you type `?neuralnet` and see the definition for stepmax it says,

> the maximum steps for the training of the neural network. Reaching this maximum leads to a stop of the neural network's training process.

For your problem, I recommend you to increase your stepmax value to 1e7 and see what happens.

The code will be,

`net.sinp <- neuralnet(nntr4 ~ nntr0 + nntr1 + nntr2 + nntr3, data=nntr,     hidden=10, threshold=0.04, act.fct="tanh", linear.output=TRUE, stepmax=1e7)`

Answer (score 3):

With `tanh` as an activation function (it is bounded), 
it is very difficult to reproduce the linear trend in your signal.

You can use linear activation functions instead,
or try to detrend the signal.

```
# Data
dx <- 1
n <- 25
x <- seq(0,by=dx,length=n+4)
y <- x + sin(x^2)
y0 <- y[1:n]
y1 <- y[1 + 1:n]
y2 <- y[2 + 1:n]
y3 <- y[3 + 1:n]
y4 <- y[4 + 1:n]
d <- data.frame(y0, y1, y2, y3, y4)
library(neuralnet)

# Linear activation functions
r <- neuralnet(y4 ~ y0 + y1 + y2 + y3, data=d, hidden=10)
plot(y4, compute(r, d[,-5])$net.result)

# No trend
d2 <- data.frame(
  y0 = y0 - x[1:n], 
  y1 = y1 - x[1 + 1:n], 
  y2 = y2 - x[2 + 1:n], 
  y3 = y3 - x[3 + 1:n], 
  y4 = y4 - x[4 + 1:n]
)
r <- neuralnet(y4 ~ y0 + y1 + y2 + y3, data=d2, hidden=10, act.fct="tanh" )
plot(d2$y4, compute(r, d2[,-5])$net.result)
```